# Apple iPhone 6s Airplane Mode Hardware

Tags: iphone

Does turning airplane on and off constantly on my iPhone 6s ruin my hardware or ruin the iPhone in any way?

Answer (score 0):

**No, this will not harm your device in any way.**

Airplane mode is a software thing, not hardware. Therefor, It cannot ruin your device.

*To have more people confirm this: See [this topic](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-maxx/175146-can-airplane-mode-hurt-phone.html) or this [one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84646/is-frequently-toggling-airplane-mode-on-off-harmful-to-ipad-hardware)*

Comment: Software 'things' can break hardware. Like overclocking, etc